# Vim: How do I map vimgrep command to avoid typing the file pattern?

Tags: vim

I usually search in my projects using `vimgrep` command in this fahsion:

```
:vimgrep /{pattern}/gj app_name/**/*.py
```

All the significant source code lives inside the `app_name` directory and I always search inside Python files, so I would like to create a command to avoid writing the search path over and over (I'm using a project specific `vimrc` for custom mappings). Something like this:

```
:proj_search {pattern}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`command`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command)

```
command -nargs=1 ProjSearch vimgrep /<args>/gj app_name/**/*.py
```

[`:h 40.2`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.2)

---

Edit: As [mcubik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1493602/mcubik) pointed out

> User-defined commands must start with a capital letter.  You
>   cannot    use `":X"`, `":Next"` and `":Print"`.  The underscore cannot be
>   used!  You    can use digits, but this is discouraged.

Comment: Thank you! Just to add a detail: I had to change the command name. User defined command names must start with uppercase and cannot contain underscore.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I will correct my answer.